# How to convert my variable to another using np.where

Tags: pandas

df['var']

```
a  start
a  start
b  middle
a  start
c  end
```

The code is working fine is below

```
conv = {'a': 'start', 'b':'middle', 'c':'end'}
df.var = df.var.map(conv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is simpliest and working nice.

But it is possible with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df.var = np.select([df.var == 'a',df.var == 'b',df.var == 'c'], 
                    ['start','middle','end'], 
                    default=None)
```

Or with 3 times [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.var = np.where(df.var == 'a', 'start',
         np.where(df.var == 'b', 'middle',
         np.where(df.var == 'c', 'end', None)))
```

Comment: one more, if i have one more variabale 'x' which i need to map to `start` do i need to create np.where(df.var == 'x', 'start')

Comment: @cdac - It is possible, but better is change `df.var == 'a'` to `df.var.isin(['a', 'x'])`